# enable/disable of submit button based on other elements of the form using zurb foundation

Tags: javascript, html, validation, zurb-foundation

I have created a form with a few inputs and a button using zurb foundation, is it possible to disable the button till all the fields of the form are being attended ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can identify all your required inputs (with a class) and then when any of them changes or get focusout-ed check if there are empty ones. If there all filled, then enable the button.

```js
// Bind the events to the inputs
// You can use any class nedded, this covers selects too
// You even can add more events to suite your needs
$('.input-required').on('focusout change', function() {
  // We instantiate a variable to hold the button status
  var buttonDisabled = false;
  // Iterate every input
  $('.input-required').each(function() {
      // If there is any empty...
      if (!$(this).val()) {
        // We say true to the disableness of the button
        buttonDisabled = true;
      }
    })
    // Set the status to the button
  $('button').prop('disabled', buttonDisabled);
});
```

```css
form {
  width: 460px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#">
  <input type="text" class="input-required">
  <input type="text" class="input-required">
  <input type="text" class="input-required">
  <input type="text" class="input-required">
  <input type="text" class="input-required">
  <input type="text" class="input-required">

  <hr>
  <button type="submit" disabled>Process</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I am sorry .. I have already created html portion of it and I do not know how the JS working for it.

Comment: @user3025288 Yes, I'm sorry, the answer was too simplistic. There is a revised version that should work with your markup ;)

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding caused by me. This helped me a lot is there any why that I can write the same function in a different page and call it ?

Comment: @user3025288 Like in another file? There is no problem with that, in fact is recommended to have a `main.js` like file to contain all global functions ;)

Comment: yes!.. so I have moved the JavaScript code to a file and how do I call it using action  ?  your logic is write but I have someother problem implementing it.

Comment: In that case I recommend you to place the script tag [before the `</body>` tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7751514/javascript-in-head-or-just-before-body) and wrap it in a [jQuery ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) and delegate the event from the body, replacing the first line with `$('body').on('focusout change', '.input-required', function() {`

Comment: Thanks a lot @AlexQuintero I would have not done it without you help.Code worked without making the above changes (and to be frank I have not worked on Jquery :( so I could not understand what the above statement meant ) anyways thanks :)