# How to toggle the class of elements in sequence?

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggleclass

I am trying to have the class of each elements change one at a time in sequence automatically. This means element 1 glows then goes off as element 2 glows and then goes off and so on. When each element has glowed once the whole sequence starts over.

```js
$('header div:first').toggleClass('highlight').nextAll().toggleClass('none');

function highlight() {
  var $off = $('header div.highlight').toggleClass('none');

  if ($off.next().length) {
    $off.next().toggleClass('none');
  } else {
    $off.prevAll().last().toggleClass('highlight');
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(highlight, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
 <div>element 1</div>
 <div>element 2</div>
 <div>element 3</div>
 <div>element 4</div>
</header>
```

It wont work as expected (elements 2 through 4 highlight all at the same time and then go off while element 1 doesnt change at all) and I dont know why. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think that extra `.none` is useless. All you need is your `.highlight`

Comment: should I take it off from where?

Comment: Everywhere, unless you include some CSS in your question that demonstrates it has an actual purpose. Just toggle your `highlight` class instead.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan  "Copy snippet to answer" button saves time

Comment: @HorsSujet woopsz sorrree :) I see now Good job!

Comment: You can use `.queue()` , `.promise()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So yes, you don't need the `.none`. Simply use your default styles and the `.highlight` class.
Get the number of items, create a `c`ounter, increment it and loop it using `%` Reminder Operator:

```js
jQuery(function( $ ) { // DOM is ready

  var $el = $("header>div"), tot = $el.length, c = 0;

  $el.eq(c).addClass("highlight"); // initial highlight

  setInterval(function() {
    $el.removeClass("highlight").eq(++c%tot).addClass("highlight");
  }, 1000);

});
```

```css
header > div           { transition:0.5s; -webkit-transition:0.5s; }
header > div.highlight { color:#f0f; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
 <div>element 1</div>
 <div>element 2</div>
 <div>element 3</div>
 <div>element 4</div>
</header>
```

Some docs:
https://api.jquery.com/eq/
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()

Comment: Seems pretty elegant but will this CSS3 stuff work in all browsers?

Comment: @AlexanderDixon yes, in all modern browsers. And even in IE<9... just without the fade efx

Comment: your code is almost the better one. Just one issue, the sequence starts from element 2. Any way to start from element 1 instead?

Comment: nevermind. I just realized you added the class to the first element and with that it works as expected. However, I cant change the class of the divs in the html because its an external include. Any way to make it work without changing the html?

Comment: Please say more about what you're doing in with the `.eq()` methods and the counter modulus.  I've never seen it used in such a way.

Comment: that did it. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

The `none` class along with the [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) calls can be a bit confusing to read through. You may be better off by simply keeping track of your current highlighted element via `div.highlight` and determining which one to target next using the updated code below :

```
function highlight() {
    // Remove the highlight from all options
    var $current = $('div.highlight');
    // Store the next one
    var $next = $current.next('div');
    // Remove all highlighting
    $('div.highlight').removeClass('highlight')
    if($next.length){
      $next.addClass('highlight');
    } else {
      $('header div:first').addClass('highlight');
    }
}
// When the document is ready
$(function() {
    // Initially set your first element as highlighted and start your interval
    $('header div:first').addClass('highlight');
    setInterval(highlight, 1000);
});
```

**Example**

You can [see an example of this in action here](http://jsbin.com/jopuzox/edit?html,output) and demonstrated below :

[image]

*Image is for example purposes only and timing may appear different than actual code executing...* **:)**

Comment: Parsing the DOM over and over again inside a loop is not the best idea.

Comment: @AlexanderDixon It's a .gif and I'm apparently not great at making perfect ones... I up-voted your comment hoping it was just trolling (the demo itself should look just fine).

Comment: @AlexanderDixon LOL :D just see jsBin Demo, because this jumpy!! just in Gif picture my friend, i think you should undo downvote !

Comment: If Rion adds in a sinppet that says "below is a image sample" I can upvote.  Sorry Rion

Comment: I added a little sentence underneath just for you @AlexanderDixon :)

Answer (score 3):

## Solution :

Change `.none` by `.highlight`, like this :

```js
$('header div:first').toggleClass('highlight');

function highlight() {
  var $off = $('header div.highlight').toggleClass('highlight');

  if ($off.next().length) {
    $off.next().toggleClass('highlight');
  } else {
    $off.prevAll().last().toggleClass('highlight');
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(highlight, 1000);
});
```

```css
.highlight {
   color:red; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
 <div>element 1</div>
 <div>element 2</div>
 <div>element 3</div>
 <div>element 4</div>
</header>
```

## Other ways :

```js
$('header div:first').toggleClass('highlight');

setInterval(function() {
  var abc = "highlight";
      $off = $('header div.' + abc),
      $next = $off.next().length ? $off.next() : $off.prevAll().last();

  $off.toggleClass(abc);
  $next.toggleClass(abc);
}, 1000);
```

```css
.highlight {
   color:red; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
 <div>element 1</div>
 <div>element 2</div>
 <div>element 3</div>
 <div>element 4</div>
</header>
```

Comment: Thanks. Your code works perfect but I have one question. You put the javascript inside <head> or right before </body>? Because I tried it on my end and it wont work.

Comment: That vanilla JavaScript case selection is tried and true.  I so need to incorporate it more in my code to `?` write more code `:` write less code`;`

Comment: @CainNuke http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10994335/javascript-head-body-or-jquery I prefer to let you to make your own choice. If you have several js lib, I advice you to use [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/).

Comment: My original code worked included in <head> but yours only works if within body. Is there any reason for that?

Comment: @CainNuke I don't know. You can use `$(document).load(function() { /* code here */ });` to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this approach.

**Javascript**

```
var highlight = function(){
$('header div').removeClass('highlight');
$('header div').each(function(i,v) {
setTimeout(function(){$(v).prev().toggleClass('highlight');$(v).toggleClass('highlight');}, i*1000);
});
setTimeout(highlight, ($('header div').length)*1000);
};
highlight();
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L0f1kbfm/1/)