# jQuery-Page not loading correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion

I recently used accordion jquery to help me expand/collapse content ( like a drop-down menu )..I used this script and placed it in the `<body>`

Script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($)
{
                    $("#accordions-727.accordions").accordion({
                            active: "",
                            event: "click",
                            collapsible: true,
                            heightStyle: "content",
                            animated: "swing",
})
                    })
```

The script is working fine but the page is not loading correctly..When I view or refresh the page, all the contents inside the drop-down menu becomes visible but once the page finishes loading everything becomes fine..Now how can I fix this?..Should I place the script in the `<head>`?

Comment: The console fires some message to you? Do you have more details?

Comment: @RPichioli no nothing

Comment: I thing I should put the script in <head> so it loads first..What do you think?

Comment: Well, I guess you should try to put it in <head> and i see no need for $ argument in the ready call.

Comment: Is this accordion from jQueryUI?

Comment: No from a wordpress plugin

Comment: This is using jQueryUI accordion implicitly, take a look in this API documentation: http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/ ... You have a wrong attribute, you have to use animate in place of animated

Answer (score 0):

This is using jQueryUI accordion implicitly @Stew.

You have a wrong attribute in your accordion setup code, use the `animate` in place of `animated`.

Take a look in this API documentation: http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion

And it's the original component demonstration: http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

I suggest you to take a look in your jQuery files too, if they are OK and in the correct order (in `<header>` section).

Another point is to put your JavaScript in `<header>` section of your HTML and be sure you have no conflict or using older jQuery files versions than the component needs.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Wont putting the script in the <header> affect page performance?

Comment: People say that JS in bottom is more performatic, Yahoo explain about it in their "best practices" topic: https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html ... There's some topics about put JS before the </body> or inside <head> in stack overflow too, take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/196702/where-to-place-javascript-in-a-html-file and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10994335/javascript-head-body-or-jquery

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in a running fiddle?

Comment: Not sure how to do that

Comment: You can add a snippet in your question and make it runnable, or using https://jsfiddle.net/ and showing us the URL to access the program.